# Structure of compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, identification

The synthetic scheme below makes reference to a reagent $\ce{(CH_3)_3COCl}$  that is added at some points in the synthesis.

What kind of structure does $\ce{(CH_3)_3COCl}$  have? The closest structure I can imagine is that of $\ce{(CH_3)_3CCOCl}$ with an extra carbon for the 3 methyl groups to be attached to. $\ce{(CH_3)_3COCl}$ seems to imply that the 3 methyl groups are attached to the carbonyl carbon (which is impossible).

[image]

Image source: IChO 2015, Problem 6

Comment: $\ce{Me3COCl}$ is possible but would require a chlorine-oxygen bond. Seems like a typo to me …

Answer (score 3):

Tert-butyl hypochlorite, cas no 507-40-4

Reagent for N-chlorination of amines and amides